# Como clicar no item da ListView e chamar outra tela?

Tags: java, android

Criei uma listView aonde mostra meus item cadastrados, como faco para ao clicar no item desejado ele abra uma nova tela com a descrição e detalhes do item?

Class onde exibe a minha tabela:

```
public class MostraTodosOsLivrosActivity extends Activity {
  private ListView lvMostraTodosOsLivros;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_mostra_todos_livros);

    Button btCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAbreCadastro);
    lvMostraTodosOsLivros = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMostraTodosOsLivros);

    btCadastro.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent it = new Intent(MostraTodosOsLivrosActivity.this, CadastroLivroActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);              
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    List<Livro> listaLivros = dbHelper.selectTodosOsLivros();

    ArrayAdapter<Livro> adp = new ArrayAdapter<Livro>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaLivros);

    lvMostraTodosOsLivros.setAdapter(adp);

}
```

Comment: Você ao menos já tem a tela que vai possuir esses detalhes? Acho que está um pouco amplo a sua pergunta, pois envolve iniciar o *Intent*, passar os dados para ele, criar uma nova *Activity*, seu layout e ainda definir os dados recebidos.

Comment: tenho sim @PauloRodrigues, só estava faltando o método que chama a tela. Mais a resposta abaixo resolveu meu problema. Mesmo assim obg pela atenção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve setar o evento [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) do `ListView`:

```
lvMostraTodosOsLivros.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // se for a partir de um fragment
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), /* activity a ser chamada */ DetailsActivity.class);
        // se for a partir de uma activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), /* activity a ser chamada */ DetailsActivity.class);
        // set no intent o id ou a position do item selecionado
        intent.putExtra("ID", id);
        intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

E na `Activity` de detalhes no método `onCreate` recebe os valores do identificadores de qual item foi clicado:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    long idSelected = getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", 0);
    long positionSelected = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);

    // Então aqui você utiliza o ID do item(caso tenha) para pesquisar no banco de dados ou a position para pesquisar na list de origem
    // E então setar a View com os detalhes do item.
}
```

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo que eu queria só que estou com uma duvida. Exemplo tenho um produto "Coca Cola" e outro "Batatas" a descrições da coca e diferente da batata certo... Quando eu clico na coca ou na batata aparece sempre a msm tela. como faco para cada um chamar um tela diferente? Estou fazendo uma tela de venda de produtos sabe? Ai cada um tem que ter uma descrição com preço diferente.

Comment: @ItalloFreire, editei a resposta veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: @Fernado Ajuda sim. So que quero uma opniao, estou desenvolvendo um app onde tem o Vendedor e o cliente. Preciso que meu vendedor consiga cadastrar no bd os produtos com preco e quantidade(radioButton), para que o cliente possa realizar seu pedido. Resumindo para que meu cliente(vendedor) possa cadastrar seus produtos diretamente no app, você recomendaria um ListView ? Ou sabe de outra forma que eu possa fazer isso ?

Comment: Ate agora no meu projeto tenho uma tela de categorias com ImageButtons, uma tela com listView com o nome dos produtos e a ultima tela com a descricao, preco, quantidade, foto e o botao de "Selecionar". O que e mais recomendado para eu fazer esse projeto?

Comment: @ItalloFreire, Nem tem como eu te recomendar nada, pois não conheço o seu projeto, nem seus requisitos e nem suas necessidades (você apenas explicou brevemente), até por que isso já seria seria completamente amplo, opinativo e fora do escopo da pergunta original.  Então o que posso te recomendar é que continue sua implementação de acordo com suas necessidades e de seu cliente, e assim que tiver duvidas de programação ou implementação vá postando-as de forma clara e objetiva aqui no site, que o pessoal te ajuda.