# Como passar informacoes da listview para uma nova activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho uma agenda sobre eventos de onde eu moro eu já consigo receber através da minha base de dados em Mysql e JSON uma lista com os títulos dos eventos. Agora queria que quando clicasse no evento fosse redirecionar para uma activity com informações do evento, mas não sei como fazer isso. Será que me podiam dar uma ajuda sou novato em android.

O meu código:

```
package com.eu.agendamarinhagrande;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.JSONParser;
import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    // JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php";

    // JSON Node names


    private static final String TAG_TITULO = "Titulo";


    // products JSONArray
    String resultado = null;

    ListView lista;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new Download().execute();
        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url_all_empresas);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String str = jsa.getString("Titulo");
                    String data = jsa.getString("Datainicio");
                    Log.e("TAG", str);
                    Log.e("TAG", data);


                    String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
                    String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

                    str = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

                    list.add(str+"\n"+data);

                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

                // updating listview
                //setListAdapter(adapter);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você só precisa implementar o método `setOnItemClickListener` na sua lista. Dê uma olhada [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62943/4337), bem semelhante à sua.

Comment: Como o paulo disse implemente o setOnClickListener e você pode passar via parcelable seus dados para a nova intent

Comment: Podem me dar exemplo pratico eu sei que é atravez do setOnClick mas como sou novato nao sei como utilizar intent etc se me poderem ajudar obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, se você pretende passar Objetos que você criou entre `Activities`, você precisa implementa-la como `Parcelable` ou `Serializable`.

Implementar sua classe como `Parcelable` ou `Serializable`, significa que você pode serializar este objeto, ou seja, escrever os valores e estrutura de um objeto em metadados de forma que você possa transferi-lo entre uma `Activity` para outra, que, por sua vez, precisa deserializar este objeto e usa-lo de maneira adequada.

Um exemplo de uma classe em `Parcelable`:

```
public class Exemplo implements Parcelable {

    private String stringExemplo;
    private int intExemplo;
    private boolean booleanExemplo;

    public String getStringExemplo() {
        return stringExemplo;
    }

    public void setStringExemplo(String stringExemplo) {
        this.stringExemplo = stringExemplo;
    }

    public int getIntExemplo() {
        return intExemplo;
    }

    public void setIntExemplo(int intExemplo) {
        this.intExemplo = intExemplo;
    }

    public boolean isBooleanExemplo() {
        return booleanExemplo;
    }

    public void setBooleanExemplo(boolean booleanExemplo) {
        this.booleanExemplo = booleanExemplo;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.stringExemplo);
        dest.writeInt(this.intExemplo);
        dest.writeByte(booleanExemplo ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    }

    public Exemplo() {
    }

    protected Exemplo(Parcel in) {
        this.stringExemplo = in.readString();
        this.intExemplo = in.readInt();
        this.booleanExemplo = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Exemplo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Exemplo>() {
        public Exemplo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Exemplo(source);
        }

        public Exemplo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Exemplo[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Exemplo de uma classe com `Serializable`:

```
public class Exemplo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String stringExemplo;
    private int intExemplo;
    private boolean booleanExemplo;

    public String getStringExemplo() {
        return stringExemplo;
    }

    public void setStringExemplo(String stringExemplo) {
        this.stringExemplo = stringExemplo;
    }

    public int getIntExemplo() {
        return intExemplo;
    }

    public void setIntExemplo(int intExemplo) {
        this.intExemplo = intExemplo;
    }

    public boolean isBooleanExemplo() {
        return booleanExemplo;
    }

    public void setBooleanExemplo(boolean booleanExemplo) {
        this.booleanExemplo = booleanExemplo;
    }
}
```

Agora que você possue um objeto serializavel, você precisa captura-lo no `onItemClickListener()` de sua `ListView`:

```
lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //Capturando o objeto associado ao item da lista
        Exemplo objetoExemplo = (Exemplo) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        //Caso você queira passar tipos primitivos
        String stringExemplo = "Algum texto";
        int intExemplo = 1;
        boolean booleanExemplo = true;

        Intent intent = new Intent(SuaActivity.this, SuaOutraActivity.class);

        //O primeiro parametro é o nome deste extra a ser capturado na sua outra Activity
        intent.putExtra("objeto_extra", objetoExemplo);
        intent.putExtra("string_extra", stringExemplo);
        intent.putExtra("int_extra", intExemplo);
        intent.putExtra("boolean_extra", booleanExemplo);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Para capturar em sua outra `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("extra_objeto")) {
            Exemplo exemplo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("extra_objeto");
        }

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("string_extra")) {
            String strintExemplo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string_extra");
        }

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("int_extra")) {
            int teste = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("int_extra");
        }

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("boolean_extra")) {
            boolean booleanExemplo = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("boolean_extra");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Bem parece me uma explicaçao bastante boa pelo que li pode dar  uma olhada neste array e dizer me como ficaria ?

Comment: http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php

Comment: Vou lhe dar o exemplo cria estar a receber na outra activity a descriçao do evento que clico na listview entao imaginemos :  evento1 clico aparece uma descriçao evento 2 aparece outra descricao , tendo em conta que isto é uma agenda tem que ser atualizada regularmente e tem que ser tudo em modo automatico na programaçao que é para agenda funcionar sempre

Comment: Da mesma maneira! Você já criou a classe modelo deste seu retorno da API. Basta implementa-la como `Parcelable` ou `Serializable`. Você pode passar o Objeto inteiro ou a descricao do evento via `String`

Comment: Ok vou tentar aqui fica atento , obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: caso tenha dificuldade, crie outra pergunta para ajudarmos!