# Como pegar valores e jogar em uma outra classe? Android

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho a seguinte classe:

```
 public class RetornaUsuarioActivity extends Activity  {    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AcessoRest ar = new AcessoRest();
    String chamadaWS;
    chamadaWS = "http://www.cordeiro-it.com.br/SOUPROGRESSO/Ctrl/recuperaUser.php";
    String resultado = ar.chamadaGet(chamadaWS);
    System.out.println(resultado);
    Log.i("JSON:",resultado);

    try {
        // Tratamento de erros
         JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resultado);
         JSONArray usuarios = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("usuarios");

         for(int i=0; i < usuarios.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject jsonobject = usuarios.getJSONObject(i);
             String nome = jsonobject.getString("nome");
             String cpf = jsonobject.getString("cpf");

             /*TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
             tv.setText(nome);*/
          }  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ERRO
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erro ao retornar dados do usuário");
    }

}
```

}

Como que eu pego e jogo os valores do **NOME e CPF** que estão naquele `for` em uma outra classe de Activity?

Tipo quero pegar estes valores para ver se o usuário existe ou não, para depois salvar em um arquivo TXT.

Comment: você pode passar valores entre `Activitys` utilizando `Parcelable` e `Serializable`, de uma olhada nessa pergunta [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70456/10315]  onde o @sicachester respondeu pela manhã pode te ajudar

Answer (score 2):

Para enviar dados:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ma);
String message = "Oi! " + editText1.getText().toString();
int i = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

Bundle param = new Bundle();
param.putString("greeting",message);
param.putInteger("NumberInteger",i);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(param);
startActivity(intent);
```

Para receber, então, na classe DisplayMessageActivity.java faça:

```
Intent it = getIntent();
Bundle param = it.getExtras();
String capturedMessage= param.getString("greeting");
Integer captured_I = param.getInteger("NumberInteger");
```